# Android multiple Handler instances listening to same looper

Tags: android

I am trying to implement Handlers in this way:

From a thread send message to main handler

```
 Handler myHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
 Message msg = myHandler.obtainMessage;
 msg.what = MY_ID;
 myHandler.sendMessage(msg);
```

In my fragment I am trying to capture the message like this

```
 Handler localHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
               if (msg.what == MY_ID)
                       do something
            }
};
```

Why this is not working when both Handlers are using the same main UI looper? In all examples I have seen both the Thread and Fragment are using same Handler reference so it might not be possible. But if so, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send the message to that handler who is observing to handle the messages like in your case that's "localHandler". You have to send a message to that handler rather than myHandler.

Comment: Yes, I know that that works. But it requires that I inject the Handler reference to all location in my code where I want to listen to the messages. I hoped that when both handlers are using same Looper they would get the same messages.

Comment: it won't work as you describe. Use RxJava publish subject or Extended live Data it will better fit in your scenario. 
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#extend_livedata

Comment: thanks, I figure out it doesn't work the way I hoped it could.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful please do upvote and mark as accepted answer. Thanks for your precious time